# Binary search code not working

Tags: python-3.x

Good afternoon everyone,
I'm trying to sort out names which are already sorted in alphabetical order. I can't figure out why my program isn't working. Any tips or pointers would be nice. Thanks.

```
def main():
    names = ['Ava Fiscer', 'Bob White', 'Chris Rich', 'Danielle Porter', 'Gordon Pike', 'Hannah Beauregard', 'Matt Hoyle', 'Ross Harrison', 'Sasha Ricci', 'Xavier Adams']
    input('Please enter the name to be searched: ', )
    binarySearch
main()
def binarySearch(names):
    first = 0
    last = len(names) - 1
    position = -1
    found = False
    while not found and first <= last:
        middle = (first + last) / 2
        if names[middle] == value:
            found = True
            position = middle
        elif arr[middle] > value:
            last = middle -1
        else:
            first = middle + 1
    return position
```

Comment: With Python, indentation is important. Can you go through the code you posted and check its identation ? I am not sure it's correct.

Comment: Oops! That's not what I had in my program. I just edited it with proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean that the program isn't working? Is it a syntax error or is the problem in the wrong results?

With the code you pasted, there are several indentation problems, but besides that, lines:

```
input('Please enter the name to be searched: ', )
binarySearch
```

are also syntactically incorrect, the comma is redundant and only the function name appearing just like that is plain wrong. If you are interested in the correctness of your algorithm, it seems alright, but the boundaries can always be tricky. My code below is working and syntactically correct, if you find it helpful. (names are numbers, but that is irrelevant in this case)

```
names = [1,2,4,5,6,8,9]

def bs(n):
    start = 0
    end = len(names)
    while end - start > 0:
        m = (start+end)/2
        if names[m] == n:
            return m
        elif n < names[m]:
            end = m
        else:
            start = m + 1
    return -1

print (bs(1))
print (bs(6))
print (bs(9))
print (bs(3))
print (bs(10))
print (bs(-8))
```

Another thing I would like to point out is that this kind of binary search is already in the python standard library, the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/bisect.html) module. However, if you are writing your own for practice or for any other reason that is just fine.

Comment: Thanks!, basically the goal was to create a main function which calls the binary search function, it is part of the problem. I guess they wanted to have two modules.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3.* then you are going to want to change 
`m = (start+end)/2` 
to 
`m = (start+end)//2`
When you do /2 it outputs a float in 3.*